# Unable to see DataSource in the Database Panel of Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver, coldfusion-8

I'm working on Cold Fusion 8 which is located on local network(Ms Windows Server 2003 R2) on my work place. I am using Dreamweaver CS6 for creating "cfm" files and connected to the local server
by creating a new site and mentioning local IP and all other details.My cold fusion files are running fine. I tested it.

I have another IP where MS Windows Server 2003 is installed and MySQL 5.5 is installed there.

What I'm trying to do ?

I'm trying to run some SQL queries using "cfquery" tag of cold fusion. For this I will need to see the list of "datasources" which are present in the "Adobe 8 Coldfusion 
Administrator". But I'm unale to figure it out how would I be able to see the list of all the data sources in the Database panel of Dreamweaver? I need to have this
list otherwise I think I won't be able to retrieve data from the database and run SQL queries.

Please let me know if someone knows any way out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.cheyennejack.com/blog/post.cfm/enable-rds-on-coldfusion-8.html

You need to enable rds on your cf server and then connect to rds from dreamweaver.